# HttpWebRequest wrong encoding determination

Tags: c#, character-encoding, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to read the html page text from site - http://konungstvo.ru/ , which has utf-8 encoding.

```
var request = _requestCreator.Create(uri);
try
{
    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        if (response.ContentType.Contains("text/html"))
        {
            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

But I'm getting `\u001f�\b\01V\u0002X\u0002��X�n\u001b�`, and so on, although code works with other sites.

Comment: You forgot to insert the actual encoding that you're using into this code snippet: `..., Encoding.))`

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to specify encoding explicitly, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the character encoding for the Latin/Cyrillic alphabet which could by [ISO/IEC 8859-5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-5) or e.g. [Windows-1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251):

```
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-5");
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
```

Using this while reading the response stream yields some cyrillic content which unfortunately isn't the correct output, too: https://dotnetfiddle.net/x8jnN8. So, I'm sorry but this isn't a real answer to your problem :/

Comment: No, this isn't correct text. There must be a string with the html of the page.